# Transform stacked tables of key value pairs to a single key value table dynamically

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, flatten

I want to dynamically convert stacked tables of key-value pairs into a single key-value table.
The input table has hundreds of key value pair tables stacked on top of each other. Every table has 3 columns.
[**The Demo Sheet**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KW2WRqYjRpPtZk9ze-y52SYXbqK34lVYZRw1U5ir6pA/edit?usp=sharing)

[image]

I tried using a healper column with this formula, but it's **not feasible** in my case.

```
={ {"Key", "Value"}; { FLATTEN( FILTER(A2:C,D2:D="Key")), FLATTEN( FILTER(A2:C,D2:D="Value")) }}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
={"Key", "Value"; FLATTEN(FILTER(A2:C, ISEVEN(ROW(A2:A)))), 
                  FLATTEN(FILTER(A2:C,  ISODD(ROW(A2:A))))}
```

[image]

or:

```
={"Key", "Value"; FLATTEN(QUERY(A2:C, "skipping 2", )), 
                  FLATTEN(QUERY(A3:C, "skipping 2", ))}
```

[image]